# SOLR RSS dataimport handler is not working

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I am trying to run RSS example of SOLR 5 which is in side of example-DIH folder. using command `sole -e dih` when I run import command ( click on execute button ) solr is just showing mw importing ... nothing else.
and result is zero documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. 
Problem was just in xml file formate. when I change my xml file and some configuration it worked for me. Here is my config file.

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="URLDataSource" />
    <document>
        <entity name="slashdot"
                pk="link"
                url="http://www.feedforall.com/sample.xml"
                processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
                forEach="/rss/channel/item"
                transformer="DateFormatTransformer">

            <field column="source" xpath="/rss/channel/title" commonField="true" />
            <field column="source-link" xpath="/rss/channel/link" commonField="true" />
            <field column="subject" xpath="/rss/channel/subject" commonField="true" />

            <field column="title" xpath="/rss/channel/item/title" />
            <field column="link" xpath="/rss/channel/item/link" />
            <field column="description" xpath="/rss/channel/item/description" />
            <field column="creator" xpath="/rss/channel/item/creator" />
            <field column="item-subject" xpath="/rss/channel/item/subject" />
            <field column="date" xpath="/rss/channel/item/date" dateTimeFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" />
            <field column="slash-department" xpath="/rss/channel/item/department" />
            <field column="slash-section" xpath="/rss/channel/item/section" />

        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Comment: But still confused about this file (http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot ) How can I write data-config.xml file even [This link ] (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler) is not working for me.